# How do I resize a JButton to fit an icon?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I was trying to make the UI of my college website and I am running into an issue, the buttons have a weird border around them

This is what it looks like now:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1neJ.png]

This is what it should look like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir0De.png]

```
public static void middleBar(JFrame frame){
        JPanel middle = new JPanel();
        middle.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,6,20,20));
        String[] items = {"UniversityERP","Award","Blackboard","CCT","CertificateIssuance","CourseEvaluationSurvey","DoctoralPortal",
        "Fastrack","HostelManagement","IDCardManagement","MobileAppCMS","OnCampusJob","StudentOutboundMobility","StudentAttendanceRecording","StudentAttendanceManagement",
        "StudentClearance","StudentPaymentCenter"};
        for(String item:items){
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Images/"+item+".png");
            JButton button = new JButton(icon);
            Dimension d = new Dimension(icon.getIconWidth(),icon.getIconHeight());
            button.setPreferredSize(d);
            middle.add(button);
        }
        JPanel middleBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        middleBar.add(middle,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(middleBar,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
```

How do I remove it?

I tried using the setPreferedSize method but that didn't work

Comment: That should be [the margin](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin(java.awt.Insets)). Try setting it to zeros, ie `button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));`.

Comment: Don't use setPreferredSize(). Each component is responsible for determining its own preferred size. The GridLayout will then make each button the same size as the largest button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by gthanop, use should set the margin to zeros.

**But just fyi what is a margin?**
A margin can be understood easily, but it is the gap between the content (of anything) from the border. You can set a margin using `button.setMargin(new Insets(top, left, bottom, right))` it takes in `Insets` which defines this offset. Here's how its given [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html)

```
java.awt.Insets.Insets(int top, int left, int bottom, int right)


Creates and initializes a new Insets object with the specified top, left, bottom, and right insets.
Parameters:
top - the inset from the top.
left - the inset from the left.
bottom - the inset from the bottom.
right - the inset from the right.
```

**Let's see it in an example**

[image: cool lil button]

I have my cool little button here. I have not modified the margins just yet.

[image: cool lil button num 2]

Here I have modified the margin insets to be top = 1, bottom = 10, right = 10 and left = 10.

[image: cool lil buttons lil bro]

And here's what it looks like with all insets zero, it's more obvious when you use an image like

[image: surprised bro]

However this does not fully remove the border and leaves a lil' line on the outside, this is the **border of the button**, what we had removed with `button.setMargin(...);` was the gap and not the border. Since we don't need it we can go ahead and remove it.

```
button.setBorder(null);
```

or use the alternative

```
Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
button.setBorder(emptyBorder);
```

[image: cool shi6]

And it should end up like this.

This is going to remove the border and make the image cover the whole button and the button will work perfectly fine.

However, I would recommend you to create a custom button or at least button UI, it would be more easier and reliable to create new buttons compared to pasting a screenshot of the button especially animating the button and all would take more effort. But if it works you leave it as it is *(trust me i know from my past experiences ;)*) nothings gonna go wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be the [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/awt/GridLayout.html) which is stretching the buttons to fit the grid cells. You might be better off using [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) or even better [MigLayout](https://www.miglayout.com/) to have better control over the layout of your components